# D3.js identifying links between nodes to change link thickness

Tags: javascript, graph, svg, d3.js

I have been setting up graphs to dynamically scale in reference to the width and height of the svg or bounding box, and with nodes and node borders this is relatively simple. By using d.depth and assigning the desired ratio to assign a relative radius to a node at a certain depth, this is giving me no problems and nodes at lower depths become smaller to avoid overlap. Then, for the node border I assign a ratio between the node radius and the thickness of the border.

This has proven to be an ideal solution to a problem that arises when adding a zoom feature by scaling the container. This is the problem:

[image]

The text, the nodes, and the node borders no longer bunch up, but the links remain the same weight.

I would also like to scale the thickness of the edges between nodes but I do not know how to identify edges so that I can either assign a thickness in relation to the radius of the parent or child node

```
d3.json("aviation.json", function(root) {
  var nodes = balloon.nodes(root),
      links = balloon.links(nodes);


var link= svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",diagonal)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("shape-rendering", "auto")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .data(nodes)
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {return (1/5000*diameter);});


  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");


  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r;})
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("opacity", "0.05")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {return d.r/600;}) //here I am referecing d.r 
                                                          //to find the stroke width.
      .attr("stroke-opacity", ".5")
      .on("Click", function(d) { return zoomClick});

var text = svg.selectAll("g.text")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.y })
      .attr("font-family", "Helvetica")
      .attr("font-size", function(d)  {return d.children ? d.r/7 : d.r/4;})                          
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {return d.r/400;})
      .attr("stroke-opacity", "1")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
```

Comment: You'll have to give us a bit more. Are you using a particular layout? How are nodes and edges computed and drawn?

Comment: Apologies. I am using several different layouts that have this issue. Currently, I am using json data and the json parser. However, I would also like to use csv, tsv or other parsers that use D3's hierarchy call.

Comment: How to you create the elements of the graph?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code. I don't exactly understand your question because I am new to this. Are you referring to appending circles?

Comment: You can see in the code snippet that I am using d.r to access the node's attributes. Is there an equivalent I can use to access edge attributes at different depths?

Comment: You can set a variable width in the same way you're setting the font size later, e.g. something like `function(d) { return (d.children ? d.children[0].r : d.r)/600; }`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is how I am doing it for the nodes radius, the node stroke and the text. I am trying to find out how to alter the link thickness based on either the attributes of the parent or child nodes, or based on the depth level.

Comment: I am still having problems with this. I have created a new question with an image of the result of Lars' suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268250/custom-link-widths-based-on-depth-or-parent-radius